# при совершение какого либо действия когда игрок подошел к обьекту и зажал на 2 сек кнопку мыши

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

```
  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)//чтобы враг умер
{
    if (other.tag == "Player"& Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
          Debug.Log("ENEMY IS DEAD");
            bool dead = false;



    }
}
```

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы при подходе к обьекту и держании кнопки мыши 2 секунды происходило какое либо действие.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала вам нужно проверить зашёл ли игрок в тригер. Если да, то ставить какой то бклевый параметр на тру. 
Потом в апдейте если этот бклевый параметр тру проверять зажата ли клавиша мыши. 
Для начала вам нужно где то глобально объявить переменные

```
bool isTriggered = false;
bool isButtonUp = false;
```

Затем проверить сработал тригер или нет

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)//чтобы враг умер
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        isTriggered  = true;
    }
}
```

Теперь вам нужно проверить зажата ли левая клавиша мыши. и если это так то запустить отсчет времени. и если клавишу отпустили то сбросить прогресс.

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isTrigered)
        StartCoroutine(TimerTick());
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        isButtonUp = true;
}


private IEnumerator TimerTick()
{
    if(isButtonUp)
        yield break;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    //таймер прошел. чудити что хотите
}
```

Comment: Больше похоже на комментарий, будьте добры расписать "ставить какой-то булевый параметр на тру..." в код, иначе этот ответ не несет никакой ценности.

Comment: Этот ответ полностью описывает алгоритм который нужно проделать что бы получить желаемый результат.

Comment: Здесь, вроде как, площадка для программистов, а не для теоретиков :)

Comment: Хах, справедливо. Но человек так будет знать что ему делать. И сможет привести код если вдруг что не выйдет. И тогда уже можно будет помочь в плане кода.

Comment: думаю нужно хотя бы ссылочки дать на то как создавать триггер, как проверять зажата ли клавиша... А лучше в примерах с кодом. А то и вправду довольно расплывчасто будет выглядеть для начинающего, коим автор вопроса явно и является.

Comment: private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)//чтобы враг умер
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player"& Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
              Debug.Log("ENEMY IS DEAD");
                bool dead = false;

            

        }
    }

Comment: примерно вот такой код? andrey

Comment: @Andrey, ну вот теперь и разбирайтесь с этим удобным кодом в комментариях :D

Comment: Хах,теперь намного веселее.

Comment: Проверку на нажатие мышки нужно перенести в апдейт. И вообще представте этот код в вашем вопросе, отредактировав его

Comment: можете подсказать как это реализовать если не сложно  @Andrey

Comment: я обновил свой ответ

Comment: Необходимо добавить колбэк для выхода из триггера.

Comment: Да, и обнулить булевые переменные, но думаю что это уже мелочи которые решит сам автор.

Comment: Второй раз на те же грабли хотите наступить?)

Comment: Ну тут уже дело автора. Вдруг ему это не нужно, мб это одноразовое событие или ещё что то. Но вообще вы правы. Скорее всего придется дописать

Comment: Нет, это не "дело автора", вы объявили `isTriggered` глобально, но нигде не присваиваете ей значение false, что несомненно поломает логику, если таких триггерных объекта как минимум 2.

Comment: @Andrey,а куда писать действие которое происходит при нажатии кнопки возле обьекта

Comment: Там где я написал комментарий. //таймер прошел, чудите что хотите